# How to change checkimages for single button?

Tags: ios4, ios5, uibutton, switch-statement

I implemented the code to check button image. Now i want to change the images in that button when i click but whenever i click it displays only single image.
 here i a implement like this

-

```
(IBAction)name:(id)sender{

currenttagvalue = [sender tag];int count = 0;

switch (currenttagvalue) {
        case 1:

            if (count == 0)
{

 [level1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"one_time_selected.png"] 

forState:UIControlStateNormal];  

count++'

}

 if (count == 1)

{

 [level1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"two_time_selected.png"] 

forState:UIControlStateNormal];  

count++'

}

 if (count == 2)
{

 [level1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"one_time_selected.png"] 


forState:UIControlStateNormal];  

count++'

}

 if (count == 2)
{

 [level1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"three_time_selected.png"] 


forState:UIControlStateNormal];  

count++'

}
```

Thank you for in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the `count` value as `static`, like:

```
static int count;
```